# Как можно объединить Си (без плюсов) и MS Excel 2007?

Tags: c, excel

Меня попросили написать небольшую программу для Excel, но я немного знаю только Си. VBA не знаю. Как написать программу на Си которая будет работать данными таблицами на Excel? С чего начать?

Comment: забить на эту идею

Comment: И еще обязательно подучить русский язык - исправьте в своем вопросе "объЕдинить".

Comment: мен орыс емеспін (я не русский)...

Comment: Ну тогда тем более слушайте, что вам русские говорят про русский язык - объЕдинить - Е вместо Я.

Comment: Вы правы...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OLE объекты

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.libxl.com/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/xlslib/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687829.aspx